# Check if an hour has passed in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I tried to make an application where every an hour has passed will add a 100.00 penalty. For example:

10:00am - on time

11:00 - 100.00 late

12:00 - 200.00 late

I'm having a hard time on how will i code that every hour / 100 penalty after 10:00 am. The code below only checks if the time has passed by 11 hours.

```
Dim time As Date
Dim CurrHour As Integer  
time = DateTime.Now
CurrHour = time.Hour

If CurrHour >= 11 Then
    penalty = "100.00"
End If

lbl_total.Text = penalty
```

Comment: Subtract the target time, i.e. a `DateTime` value, from the current time, i.e. `Date.Now`.  That will give you a `TimeSpan`, from which you can get the `TotalHours` property value.  Call `Math.Truncate` and pass that value to get just the full hours and multiply the result by 100.  That will give you your total penalty.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the penalty you only need this in your code:

```
Dim _penalty As Integer = (Now.Hour - 10) * 100.0
```

Comment: Ahh i see, so i can use `Now.Hour`  Thank you so much